# React - Check if function returns true but always runs code for false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, jsx, boolean-logic

I bet this has something to do with asynchronicity.

Basically, I am checking if a string (an answer to a question) already exists, and if so, the page should just display a message, otherwise should add the new question to an array.

So in order to refactor the code, I have created a function called `isDuplicateAnswer` (yes, it's bound to the component). Here is the code for it:

```
 isDuplicateAnswer() {
    if (this.state.answersToCurrentQuestion.length > 0) {
      this.state.answersToCurrentQuestion.map(answer => {
        if (this.state.answerTextTyped === answer.text) {
          console.log("true"); // executed twice but then adds it to the array (not supposed to)
          return true;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Based on this check the code will do the following:

```
if (
      event.target.id === "submitAnswer" &&
      this.state.answerTextTyped !== null &&
      this.isDuplicateAnswer()
    ) {
      console.log("Something is wrong"); // This line is never executed (no log, no message)
      return this.props.handleMessage(
        "There is already another answer with this text. Please add a different one."
      );
    } else if (
      event.target.id === "submitAnswer" &&
      this.state.answerTextTyped !== null &&
      !this.isDuplicateAnswer()
    ) {
      console.log("Everything OK"); // not displayed but rest of the code goes through (answer added)
      this.setState({ answerText: this.state.answerTextTyped }, () => {
        (() => {
          let answersToCurrentQuestion = [
            ...this.state.answersToCurrentQuestion,
          ];
          answersToCurrentQuestion.push({
            text: this.state.answerText,
            isCorrect: this.state.isCorrectAnswer,
          });
          this.setState({ answersToCurrentQuestion });
          if (this.state.isCorrectAnswer === true) {
            this.incrementCorrectAnswers();
          }
        })();
        (() => {
          this.props.handleMessage("");
          this.setState({
            isValid: true,
            isCorrectAnswer: false,
            answerTextTyped: null,
          });
          this.refreshAnswerTypedForm();
          this.getAnswerTypedForm();
        })();
      });
    }
```

My problem is that if `isDuplicateAnswer` is `false`, as my log says "Everything is Ok", but when it returns `true`, the answer is created, resulting in an error due to the HTML key being not unique, even though the log from `isDuplicateAnswer` is displayed twice.

Given that the other two checks in the guard are working correctly, what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT

this is the state right before clicking on "Add Answer", which id is `submitAnswer`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong in your code. I will list the ones that are most obvious to me:

1) Your `isDuplicateAnswer()` method will always return `undefined` which under `if` condition will always evaluate to `false`. That is why `Something is wrong` is never executed - it will never go to that block.

2) This one is linked to `1)` above. Basically `map` doesn't return a `boolean`, moreover you have to return the result of the function which you're not doing as well. To fix this, use a method like [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which does return a boolean:

```
isDuplicateAnswer() {
       return this.state.answersToCurrentQuestion.some(answer => this.state.answerTextTyped === answer.text);
        // If we find that answer already exists, some will return true, otherwise false.
  }
```

3) In the 2nd block, do not check for `event.target.id === "submitAnswer" && this.state.answerTextTyped !== null` twice. Just do:

```
if (event.target.id === "submitAnswer" && this.state.answerTextTyped !== null) {
    if (isDuplicateAnswer()) {
        console.log("Something is wrong");
        return this.props.handleMessage("There is already another answer with this text. Please add a different one.");
        // No setState call to change anything.
    } else {
        // Call setState and add your answer.
    }
```

Comment: `some` is a more straightfoward alternative to `find` that returns an actual boolean (both should work though). Also, the length check is redundant. The whole function could just be `return this.state.answersToCurrentQuestion.some(answer => this.state.answerTextTyped === answer.text)`

Comment: Yes `Jacob`, almost forgot about `some`. Updating :)

Comment: Thank guys, I probably would have never made it...I am new to JS